# C# Silverlight RIA Services Authentication - Step By Step How-To?

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

#### The Scenario

I have been following Brad Abrams Silverlight With Ria Tutorials In order to build a web-based application. I have implemented my own custom version of the application that is built throughout the tutorials and am hoping to add in some authentication to it.

#### The Problem

I have followed [this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/07/13/business-apps-example-for-silverlight-3-rtm-and-net-ria-services-july-update-part-3-authentication.aspx) also by Brad Abrams on Authentication which was totally useless. I have also looked at multiple other tutorials on Silverlight Authentication but they too are very ambiguous in assuming knowledge etc. (I have never implemented website authentication ever before).

#### The Question

Does anyone have (or could you write one) a step-by-step guide for total dummies to implementing Silverlight with RIA Services Authentication? It can be totally basic, I just need to be able to define two users (an admin and a guest) and have the site only be accessible to these two accounts.

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain why Brad's tutorial was totally useless to you? That would help in recommending other resources.

Comment: I'll forward this to Brad to see if he or one of his team can distill this down to Goober's query, as maybe a second pass at in the context above may help?

Scott Barnes / Microsoft

Comment: It was considered to be useless because there was no in-depth detail about the process of enabling authentication. I understand that you can setup the application to prompt a login screen when particular methods are executed, but the process of actually being able to define a list of users and roles with specific passwords was simply not defined. It's a shame because the rest of the tutorials Brad presents were darn good.

Comment: I just added RIA Services auth to my app and I agree with this post.  Also read Brad's tutorial but it really isn't an A-Z of RIA Services Auth - for example what exactly does <appsvc:WindowsAuthentication> do?  This subject needs a large 20 page "getting started" on msdn like the one for ASP.NET Application Services in SL.

Comment: @James Cadd - Any chance you could do a quick walkthrough to help me out!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brad Abrams has a blog post up now further explaining authentication.

[Brad Abrams](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/10/05/business-apps-example-for-silverlight-3-rtm-and-net-ria-services-july-update-part-26-authentication-and-personalization.aspx)

Comment: Yeah I had a chat with Tim Heuer last night actually and he talked me through it, just been too busy to answer this.

Answer (score 3):

Making RIA Services to work with authentication can be just using standard forms auth or windows authentication. Its just code.  If you don't know how to get Forms Auth or Windows Auth working with ASP.NET, that's where i'd start.